# How to create 'responsive' lists: creating multiple columns to fit available width?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my old fixed-width world, I could take a variable X # of elements, divide by three and distribute the data across three columns fairly efficiently:

[image: Fixed Width Example]

In this new fangled responsive world, the best solution I've come up (so far) is to split data into fixed-size buckets (say 5) and then let the chunked lists float left:

[image: Responsive - but ghetto List Example]

This works great when you have a list that's pretty long, but when you have a small list - there are A LOT of horizontal pixels that can get wasted.  It also works pretty well if one of the elements ends up being SUPER long/wide, and it can effectively push the next group of lists down under it.

I'm currently using Bootstrap3, but open to a pure CSS solution for this.

Is there a great way to do responsive multi-column lists (optimizing for available width on the device)

Comment: wait...isn't that what bootstrap gird does? Maybe i am missing something here...

Comment: The solution is similar, but subtly different enough to be a pain.  Bootstrap (generally) gives you the capability to split it into say 3rds, (like my fixed width example), but it doesn't let you say I have X elements, now go divide them into (whatever is needed) Y groups that will automatically fit the available width available.  This could be a pipe dream.

Answer (score 0):

what if you just make 3 responsive columns in a row:

Edit: added media query to make 3 columns 1 column

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/pMF2m/8/)

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner1">Hello</div>
    <div class="inner2">World</div>
    <div class="inner3">!</div>
</div>

.outer {
    width: 100%;
}
.inner1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 32%;
}
.inner2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    margin-left: 2%;

}
.inner3 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {   /* small mobile sizes */

.inner1, .inner2, .inner3 {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    }
}
```

[**This Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/pMF2m/9/) is updated with the media query that makes the 3 columns into 1 column on screen widths <= 420px

Comment: The primary problem I have with setting width to the inner-divs is the "waste" if you have a column, who's list values are short.  Effectively, I don't like having to pre-specify the number of columns I want to split the data into, and just let the items create their own columns based upon the available width.  My original fixed-width solution was FAR from perfect, and as I move to a responsive design I was hoping to finally fix this with a good design pattern.

Comment: these are not fixed widths. `width: 300px` is fixed. these are responsive widths. If what you mean by "the available width" is that you want these three columns to become 1 column when someone is say, on a mobile device, you need to do that in media queries. its simple.  perhaps I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I understand being able to fix a percentage of real estate like (33% above) to emulate a fixed width design.  I think my design was inherently flawed though.  If there was a way for me to have 5 columns if all of the data fit in equal 20% increments, or if I can only have 2 columns/etc/etc I would love to figure out if there is a way for the number of columns to match whatever is appropriate for the device + content length.

Comment: if you mean that because bootstrap is a 12 column grid and so only allows for 1,2,3,4,6,12 columns, all you need to do step out of bootstraps classes and create your own custom classes for 5 columns of 20% (really they need to be a hair under 20% each)

Comment: Also, this doesn't "emulate a fixed width design".  This is a *Fliud* or *Responsive* width design. The columns resize with the window.  You change layout via Media Queries.  Bootstrap is simply a *Framework* that utilizes pre-written classes and media queries. You can still write your own as I did above.  You are not restricted to the classes and media queries bootstrap provides you with.

Comment: [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/pMF2m/11/) shows you 5 fluid/responsive columns.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something in that fiddle, it just shows 5 columns that resize widths in chrome, not necessarily rebalancing your list automatically.  I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15204924/1566477 on CSS Multi-Columns which in more inline with what I was hoping to use/do.  My only gripe there is I, again need to have a pre-determined number of columns

Comment: Yes, with pure css you will need to have a pre-determined number of columns, however, you can change that number of columns based on the width of the window/viewport with media queries. Perhaps you are confusing responsive with dynamic.  A reponsive site is one whos layout responds to the many different device/browser/window size. It does not respond to the content that is loaded. You would need javascript or another more powerful scripting language to accomplish that